# Oracle - Concatenate column value with string at runtime

Tags: java, sql, oracle

How can I concatenate a column value with a string from my java program at runtime?

Say I have a table 'Car' and there is a numeric column (engine_size) in it and I want to build a statement such that I concatenate the runtime value of a car's engine_size column value with a string in my java program .e.g (engine_size + '_cc')  - do I need to use the 'convert' function?

Comment: sorry, reference the runtime value you mean? Any SQL query is going to be runtime execution only.

Comment: Yes the runtime value. I want to concatenate it with something else.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the original question

Comment: Can you please post ur JDBC code as well ?

Comment: Add `concat(engine_size,'_cc')` or `engine_size||'_cc'` to ur query

Comment: ah ok thanks. 'concat' is an oracle function? Is this type of behaviour known as dynamic sql?

Comment: No.. it is not dynamic. and yes, CONCAT is oracle's inbuilt function

Comment: To concatenate the string use the below sample, `PP.FIRSTNAME || ' ' || PP.LASTNAME Name`